# How to setup Azure DevOps CI/CD for .NET project for Azure Function App

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-functions

I have a .Net project created in Visual Studio for Azure function App. The function app should be deployed into azure resource group.

Manually I can deploy it with the following commands.

To build:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

To deploy:

```
az login
az account set --subscription <id>
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resourceGroup> -n <functionName> --src publish.zip
```

I want to automate this process through Azure DevOps, as when I push this code (vs project) into azure repository, I want to build this automatically and deploy through CI/CD.

I have been searching this, but was unable to find any helpful resource.

Can someone provide me step by step guide on this with providing examples to create `.yml` files if required??

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a pipeline to deploy the function App. You can follow this [blog](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurefunctions/) to see how to configure and deploy the function to Azure.

For ex, follow the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=csharp),

```
pool:
      vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'
steps:
- script: |
    dotnet restore
    dotnet build --configuration Release
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration Release --output publish_output'
    projects: '*.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    zipAfterPublish: false
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    artifactName: 'drop'
```